# Qt 5.5 (Q_ENUM causing compile error)

Tags: qt, qt5.5

I've just upgraded Qt from 5.3.2 to 5.5.0.  A project (which uses QAbstractTableModel) which compiles just fine in 5.3.2 does not compile in 5.5.0, reporting the following error (numerous times):

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h:241: error: ISO C++     forbids declaration of 'Q_ENUM' with no type [-fpermissive]
     Q_ENUM(LayoutChangeHint)
                        ^
```

The errors are entirely in Qt's files, not mine.  I'm using gcc491.  Below is a few interesting bits from my project file.  Any ideas?

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MyApp
QT += core widgets gui
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g -std=c++11
```

Comment: you have a possible conflict of enum and class LayoutChangeHint, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452329/error-iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-object-with-no-type

Comment: The thing is, correct me if I'm wrong, that's Qt's conflict, not mine.  I don't have any subclassed LayoutChangeHint.

Comment: Not sure. I can find only enum LayoutChangeHint { NoLayoutChangeHint, VerticalSortHint, HorizontalSortHint } in Qt. Do you see anything else related causing conflict?

Comment: Okay, I found it -- my .project file still had the 5.3.2 directory in the INCLUDEPATH.  Big problem. ;)  Thanks for the replies.. they got me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Bonehead move.  In QtCreator I pointed to the 5.5.0 version of qmake, but in the .project file 5.3.2 was still in the INCLUDEPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after upgrading to Qt5.5 on my Mac.  It turned out that I had, at some time, installed QT via homebrew.  I tried to do a 'brew update' but even though it updated QT5, the problem persisted... and after searching I found that there may be issues outstanding.

To fix the problem I uninstalled QT via Homebrew (**brew uninstall qt**) AND I uninstalled QT using the '**MaintenanceTool**' app that was in my QT install directory.  Then I reinstalled Qt5.5 again using the online installer tool.  That sequence finally did the job.

It appears to be necessary to make sure that the old QT libraries / links are gone so that the Qt5.5 installer can set up the ones so that they are found properly.  Those old symbolic links that Homebrew left in were somehow not being updated or replaced by the Qt5.5 installer.  I found that out after repeated failures.  Hopefully this saves someone else the headache that I've developed.